# Trouble with iterating through std::set (c++)

Tags: c++, iterator, set

I am having problems with sets all day. Some I can solve, others not. This one is bugging me since the morning, and I have run out of patience. Please help, mighty stackoverflow!

So, I have a set which contains a custom object of mine, its called "vect" and is based on eigen::matrix. That means, I get values from vects with the [] operator.

```
set<vect*> *tvps=getTheSet();

for (set<vect*>::iterator iter = tvps->begin(); iter != tvps->end(); ++iter)
{
    vect v= **iter;   // Don't really know why two asterisks,
                      // but my compiler would complain
    int x=v[0];
    int y=v[1];
    doStuffWith( v[0],v[1]);

}
```

Now, this will compile and run and everything. But the values I get from the iterator are 30% trash:

```
x: 110   y: 90
x: 230   y: 130
x: 250   y: 100
x: 230   y: 130
x: 110   y: 290
x: 140   y: 260
x: 180   y: 280
x: 150   y: 210
x: -2147483648   y: 0
x: 180   y: 280
x: 170   y: 230
x: 240   y: 270
x: -2147483648   y: 0
x: -429917536   y: 0
x: 0   y: -2147483648
```

I checked at the point where the set was put together which values where put in. Only the ones between 10 and 300.. as intended. How comes I find others in it? Did I screw up with the iterator?

Comment: The first * is needed to obtain the object pointed to by your iterator, which is a pointer. To get the object pointed to by *iter, you have to dereference it, hence the second *.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with your printing, I think the problem is going to be with your adding the elements to the columns.  This is evident because you have garbage values in-between good values.

Comment: Add code for `vect`'s definition, and how you are building the set.

Comment: No, your problem is not with the iterator. I would rather guess the problem is storing pointers and losing what's pointed to.

Comment: Since you are copying what is in the `std::set` into a a temporary `vect` object, have you checked your `vect` objects copy constructor for any issues?

Comment: I just found a function which generated new vects instead of passing pointers from the main instance.. yeah, it realy looks like pointer issues, that would explain as well why the buggy entries vary from call to call. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possibilities as to why this is happening to you:

- Are you reusing the set. If yes, do you `clear()` it between reuses ?
- You are storing pointers to vectors in the set, are you changing the vectors inside the set ?

Perhaps you want to store the pointer to the vector because otherwise the compiler gives you an error due to the fact that it doesn't know how to compare two vectors. Why don't you try to implement the [comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yy2xd0h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) function and store vectors directly ? that way your work would be a lot easier and much less error prone.

Also the problem you have now is that the elements in the set don't seem to be ordered.. in fact they are ordered by the pointer value, and not by X and Y (and I suppose that's what you want)

Comment: I didnt notice up to now, that there were identical vectors in the set.. lol. Thx for the link, thats what I'll do.

Answer (score 1):

You have a set of pointers to vectors. In `**iter` first you dereference iterator, then pointer laying inside.

Keeping pointers can also be causing your problem: if you freed or forgot to initialize some of them, result would be rubbish.